# jQuery replaceWith not loading div properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jQuery but am hoping to replace a `<div>` with another that contains a slideshow when I click on a link. The problem with my code however is that when I click the link, the `<div>` I want to load isn't showing. Instead I just see `div.slidesContainer` for example.

My HTML:

```
<div id="leftText">
  <h2>Heading.</h2>
  <p>Text. <a href="/" id ="startSlide" %>'Learn more.'</a></p>
</div>
<div id="slide">
<div class="slides_container">
  <div>
    <h1>Slide heading.</h1>
      <p>Slide text.</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

My jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $("a#startSlide").click(function(){
        $('div#leftText').replaceWith('div#slide');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Here's a jsFiddle if it'll help: http://jsfiddle.net/HR43b/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass a selector, not a string:

```
$(function() {
    $("a#startSlide").click(function() {
        $('div#leftText').replaceWith($('#slide'));

        $('#slide').css('visibility', 'visible');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HR43b/3/

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass an HTML or jQuery object to replaceWith: http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

> **.replaceWith( newContent )**
>
> newContentThe content to insert. May be an HTML string, DOM element,
>   or jQuery object.
>
> **.replaceWith( function )**
>
> functionA function that returns content with which to replace the set
>   of matched elements.

String:

```
$('div.inner').replaceWith('<h2>New heading</h2>');
```

Object:

```
$('div.third').replaceWith($('.first'));
```

Callback:

```
$('div.container').replaceWith(function() {
  return $(this).contents();
});
```

Comment: Ah, right. Thanks for the reminder that HTML or a jQuery object is required.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$('div#leftText').replaceWith('<div id="slide"></div>');
```

Or

```
$('div#leftText').replaceWith($('div#slide'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
div#slide {
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

your `<div>` is hidden.. before replacing with other content change its behavior to visible. 
and then use `replaceWith`

your altered jsfiddle

```
 $(function(){
        $("a#startSlide").click(function(){
            $('div#slide').css('visibility','visible');
            $('div#leftText').replaceWith($('div#slide'));
            return false;
        });
    });
```